# Symfony Forms: "Array to string conversion" exception in modified DateType class

Tags: forms, symfony, formbuilder

I'd like to build a custom DateType class. In order to do this, I copied the class *Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\DateType* to my src/ directory and changed the class name and `getName()`.

```
<?php

namespace FooBar\CoreBundle\Form\Type;

use Symfony\Component\Form\AbstractType;
// ...

class MonthType extends AbstractType
{
    // ...

    public function getName()
    {
        return 'month';
    }

    // ...
}
```

I also registered the new type:

```
foobar.form.type.month:
    class: FooBar\CoreBundle\Form\Type\MonthType
    tags:
        - { name: form.type, alias: month }
```

However if I try to use my new type, an exception (`Array to string conversion in /var/www/foobar/app/cache/dev/twig/4d/99/945***.php`) is thrown:

```
public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
{
    $default = new \DateTime('now');
    $builder
        ->add('season', 'month', array('data' => $default))
    ;
}
```

Note: If I change `'month'` to `'date'` everything works flawlessly.

Does anyone know why the exception is thrown and how I can get rid of it?

Answer (score 1):

### How to fix

You have to define the block `month_widget` and use as form field template to make sf2 render the field properly.

For instance, write below in your .twig.

```
{% form_theme form _self %}

{% block month_widget %}
<input type="text" value="{{ value.year }}">
<input type="text" value="{{ value.month }}">
{% endblock %}
```

and customize the presentation as your like.

The default theme file `Symfony/Bridge/Twig/Resources/views/Form/form_div_layout.html.twig` may help.

See below for more details.
http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/form/create_custom_field_type.html#creating-a-template-for-the-field

### Cause of error

Symfony2 does not have the rendering block named `month_widget`.

`MonthType` that you created is child of `FormType` (because inherited getParent() returns 'form')

`month_widget` could not be found (because you haven't defined it yet), so it next tries to render `form_widget`.

In `form_widget`, there is only simple text field like `<input type="text" value="{{ value }}" ...`, and fails here because value is not a scalar.

The `value` actually isn't a DateTime but array because of `DateTimeToArrayTransformer` used in the class.
(as class name says, DateTime is converted into array)

So, the error is `Array to string conversion`.